# PHP - how to make a count button with variable?

Tags: php

Im trying to make a counter with php using post method, but im not being able to count after the first click. Anyone has an idea? I already tried to unset the button but did not work.

```
`<?php
$i = 0;

if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
    $i += 1;
    echo $i;
}
?>

<form action="" method="post">
    <button type="submit" name="submit" onclick="">add</button>
</form>`
```

Comment: For every execution of this code you set `$i = 0`. So every time you execute this `$i` is either 0 or 1 (if `isset($_POST["submit"])` is true). You need to use some sort of database if you want to count past 1.

Comment: If the counter is per user, then you can store the value in a session and increment that. If the counter should be the same for all users, then you need to store the value somewhere, like in a database as suggested above.

Comment: If you intend to save it for a session, you can use the variable $ _SESSION ['COUNT'] at the post of the variable $ i, but the count will start over once the session has expired. Instead if you want the count not to be lost you have to choose a way to save it, if you don't want to use a DB you can also use a text file.

Answer (score 0):

Please set the session to 0 (if it does not exist), and then add 1 each time

You may use the following codes

```
<?php
session_start();

if (! isset($_SESSION["i"]) ){
$_SESSION["i"] = 0;
}


    $_SESSION["i"] += 1;
    echo $_SESSION["i"];
?>

<form action="" method="post">
    <button type="submit" name="submit" onclick="">add</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
   session_start();
   // Page was not reloaded via a button press
   if (!isset($_POST['submit'])) {
       $_SESSION['i'] = 1; // Reset counter
   }
?>

<form method='post'>
<input name='submit' type="submit" value='count'>
<h1><?php echo $_SESSION['i']++ ?></h1>
</form>
```